# is there any solution to edit a date in angular4?

Tags: angular, date

hello i'm trying to edit a date in my app using angular 4 but it didni't work

i'm getting this warning in my console
The specified value "1557317153000" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"using this field

Comment: What is `1557317153000`? Is it a unix time stamp (milliseconds from Epoch)? If so you will need to convert it first. I would recommend moment.js to do this. Then, based on your input control, you can either use that or get a javascript Date or get the format string.

Comment: Post the piece of code that's attempting to edit the date so we can see what you're trying to use.

Comment: You should first look into [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then take a look at [Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) & [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: i'm using angular 4 and i don't know how to solve this

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

What you have over there is the Unix  time stamp, as explained on the comments. You can convert it `yyyy-MM-dd` using angular's [datepipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), and it will work across most, if not all Angular (2+ and beyond) versions.

```
this.datePipe.transform(1557317153000, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

In order to use it, you will need to import it on your component.ts,

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

As well as including it on your module's providers.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

Check out the demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-example-tnvyam?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format in your TypeScript file or in HTML file using angular inbuilt date pipe.

**1. TypeScript:**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'; 
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    console.log(this.datePipe.transform(1557317153000, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
}
```

**2. HTML:**

```
<div>{{dateValue | date:'short'}}</div>
```

A detailed information on angular Date pipe can be obtained [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: i'm using input to edit date <input type="date" class="form-control border-input" name="date" placeholder="date " [(ngModel)]="client.datecreation"> but i don't know how to convert this date